# Is it possible to update a MacOS app without requiring admin privilege?

Tags: macos, software-update, auto-update

I use an app called Workflowy on MacOS. I need to use a separate account on my Mac that doesn’t have admin privileges right now. Whenever Workflowy has an update, I need to enter the admin username and password to install it. This is expected in of itself, but sometimes this happens several times a day, and gets to be quite distracting.

If I click cancel here, I’m prompted perhaps 15-30 minutes later. If I move this screen to the bottom right corner of the screen where only the top left corner of the window is visible, I am able to ignore it, but oddly so long as this window is open, Mac needs to run a core at 100% CPU and this drains my battery.

Is there a way to work around this without getting admin access on this Mac account?

PS: I've also contacted Workflowy for ideas on their end.

[image]

Comment: Did you check whether the application allows to disable automatic updates in its preferences?

Comment: You can install the app in your home folder, typically in ~/Applications.

Comment: I notice that the dialog is asking to install a _new helper tool_. You might have to go to System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy tab to see if this helper tool is asking for access to some element of macOS or your user space. You will need to authenticate with admin credentials.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this app has a decent online presence, I’ll assume you’re interested in a general answer. https://workflowy.com/downloads/mac/

You don’t need a helper tool for most apps, but some will need them. So the general answer is you should be able to test installing any app in your home folder. If you want to be tidy, make an Applications folder inside your home folder and drop the app there.

Past that, it’s up to each application to work or not. Keep in mind developers make an intentional choice to not work as a self contained app that can run from anywhere, so you do have to choose what you run just like they choose what to make.

Until you hear back from the maker, it’s likely you’re blocked by design here and need to get admin assistance in this specific case.